# Including libraries that need external files in iOS project

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

There are some 3rd party in my code, like the World Magnetic Model or GeoTrans. Both read in files from the current directory when compiled as command line binaries, which is no problem. However, when I include that code in my iOS project, for some reason I have trouble making that work.

In the 3rd Party code, the file is read with fopen, like:

```
MODELFILE = fopen(filename, "r");
```

where filename is something like "wmm.cof" and MODELFILE ends up being NULL (0x0).

When I check my app bundle, I do see a file called wmm.cof in the same (root) directory as the binary of my app, but no luck.

How can I handle that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to do something like:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"wmm" ofType:@"cof"];
MODELFILE = fopen([path cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], "r");
```

if you want to keep the file that code is in portable, you may want to move the objc code to a separate file and just return a `const char *`

Comment: This code is in an external C library that I have no control over, besides changing the source code of course. Injecting Objective-C code into that doesn't compile. Am I missing something?

Comment: yeah, to compile objc the source file name needs to end in ".m" or ".mm" (as opposed to ".c", ".cpp" etc).

".m" = objc
".mm" = objc++

Comment: Right, but I can't (or don't want to) change all the external library's .c files to .m files.

Comment: you'd just need to change the one file. alternatively, create a .h file with a function something like: 

`(const char *)getPathForResource(const char *fileName, const char *fileExtension);`

then create a .m with:

`(const char *)getPathForResource(const char *fileName, const char *fileExtension) {
  NSString *fn = [NSString stringWithCString:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSString *fe = [NSString stringWithCString:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fn ofType:fe];
  return [path cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}`

Comment: yikes.. that's ugly.. anyway, you should then be able to do:

`MODELFILE = fopen(getPathForResource("wmm", "cof"), "r");`

note that i've just typed all this into the small comment dialog box so i'm not sure it compiles.. but that should basically be what you want.. :)

Comment: Thanks! In a dummy moment I realized that I do have control over the filename before passing it into the C function, so I can do it as you originally suggested. Accepted!